# Using a string as Function name

Tags: ruby, string

I have to made a generic function which is used for the purpose of calling many other functions depending upon the accesses im getting.
For Ex:

```
def func1

   @access = ['public','private','protected']
   for acc in @access
       @temp = "get_"+acc[1]+"_data"
   end
end

def get_public_data
end

def get_private_data
end

def get_protected_data
end
```

but @temp is taking it as a string and assigning it to it.
Please help in this ASAP.

Thank You

Comment: Please give us some more info and an example.

Comment: Its ruby, or at least seams to be with the @var_name for member variables of a class and with the end blocks and lack of colons

Comment: I hope you realize acc[1] will be "u" for "public" and "r" for both "private" and "protected". Perhaps you just meant acc.

Comment: Well, actually, for Ruby versions prior to 1.9, it will return 117 for "public" and 114 for the latter two, which is even more nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, methods are actually messages. So you can send the message name using, yup, the `send` method:

```
s = 'xyz'
i = s.send 'length'
# i = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@temp = send "get_#{acc[1]}_data"
```

Use `#{acc[1]}` instead of "+"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what language you are using, but some languages i.e. Perl have an  [eval()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) functions which does what you are trying.

If you use Perl or Python you might try something like

> @temp = eval("get_"+acc[1](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)+"_data")

Comment: Thnx Buddy 
im developing it in Ruby On Rails