# Use a string to access a local variable by name

Tags: ruby

I'm new to this but I have the following code:

```
when /^read (.+)$/
   puts "Reading #{$1}:"
   puts $1.description.downcase
```

I would like to use $1 as a variable that I can call methods on, currently the interpreter returns a `"NoMethodError: undefined method 'description' for "Door":String"`.

**Edit**:

For example:

```
door = Item.new( :name => "Door", :description => "a locked door" )
key  = Item.new( :name => "Key",  :description => "a key"         )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of _[Using a string as a variable at run time in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881239/using-a-string-as-a-variable-at-run-time-in-ruby-on-rails)_ or _[Using a String as a Function Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877882/using-a-string-as-function-name/878174)_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide more details of your code setup to get a good answer (or for me to figure out which question this is a duplicate of :). What kind of variables are referenced by `$1`? Here are some guesses:

1. If this is actually a method on the same instance, you can invoke this method by:

   ```
   # Same as "self.foo" if $1 is "foo"
   self.send($1).description.downcase
   ```
2. If these are instance variables, then:

   ```
   # Same as "@foo.description.downcase"
   instance_variable_get(:"@#{$1}").description.downcase
   ```
3. If these are local variables, you can't do it directly, and you should change your code to use a Hash:

   ```
   objs = {
     'foo' => ...,
     'key' => Item.new( :name => "Key", :description => "a key" )
   }
   objs['jim'] = ...
   case some_str
     when /^read (.+)$/
       puts "Reading #{$1}:"
       puts objs[$1].description.downcase
   end
   ```

Comment: My Variables look like this:
key = Item.new( :name => "Key", :description => "a key" )
Key is referenced by $1

Comment: @Jake Then you have a bad (but common) design and you should instead be storing them in a Hash per #3 above.

Comment: What's the alternative that you propose to this bad design? If it's too long to explain, a quick keyword I should Google would be helpful.

Comment: @Seanny123 It's spelled out above, and in my comments: use a Hash to store your data instead of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you matched a string like "read Door" with /^read (.+)$/. So $1 = "Door" and it raised the above error. If you want to *downcase* that string, just use:

> $1.downcase

Comment: Thats right, Though I want to print the description stored with it. e.g. puts $1.description.downcase. The variable that stores this is door = Item.new( :name => "Door", :description => "a locked door" )