# `send` alternative for lambda in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dynamic, lambda, metaprogramming, send

`send` does not work for lambda in Ruby:

```
>> def mymethod; end
=> :mymethod
>> send('mymethod')
=> nil

>> mylambda = ->{}
=> #<Proc:0x9f2fe28@(pry):136 (lambda)>
>> send('mylambda')
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `mylambda' for main:Object
```

How do I dynamically call a lambda via a string?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access local variables by name without using `eval`.

Here are a few alternatives you could try:

- Storing the lambda in a `Hash`:

  ```
  hash = {
    'mylambda' => ->{ 'foo' }
  }
  hash['mylambda'].call # => "foo"
  ```
- Storing the lambda in an instance variable:

  ```
  @mylambda = ->{ 'foo' }
  instance_variable_get('@mylambda').call # => "foo"
  ```
- Creating a temporary method using the lambda

  ```
  mylambda = ->{ 'foo' }
  define_method :temp, &mylambda
  send(:temp) # => "foo"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the correct `Binding` for the context of your local variable, you can use `Binding#local_variable_get` to get the value of the local variable. And to get a `Binding` for the current context, you can use `Kernel#binding`:

```
binding.local_variable_get(:mylambda).()
```

Comment: THIS is the perfect answer. Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You cant use send to invoke lambda. But you can use eval('mylambda').call to invoke

Comment: you meant outer variable, the variable defined in some other context. ? if that so,  how you even try to use send.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a lambda method you can either

```
mylambda.call
# => nil
```

or

```
mylambda.()
# => nil
```

---

If you want to call the lambda using a string as its variable name you can't - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920841/use-a-string-to-access-a-local-variable-by-name) for alternatives of how to get other references by their names)

Comment: Two more ways: [Proc#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [Proc#yield](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Proc.html#method-i-yield).